# Two questions about Wakari.io

Tags: jupyter-notebook

(1) How do you "un-share" a bundle? (I know, this must be in the documentation. But I really can't find it. Sorry!)

(2) Is there any kind of user mailing list for Wakari, where questions like the above would be better targeted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, well I ended up eventually finding it. So, just in case anybody else should look here. You can pull down a menu under your user name. One of the options is "settings." Within that there is an item called "sharing." When you click on that you get a list of your currently shared bundles with an option to delete them.